# rstudio version 0.99.878 source editor pop out window lagging

Tags: r, rstudio

I recently downloaded `rstudio` version 0.99.878 and was really excited about using the pop out source editor for easier viewing,coding, and editing experience.

Now when I edit in the separate window I find the editing to lag about a half a second and it makes coding many times slower.

I have never had this problem in `rstudio` before, and the lag is considerably reduced when I have the source editor in the program.

My computer is running fine and I have a:

- i5 dell latitude
- 8gb ram
- SSD drive
- my other programs do not lag.

I am running r version 3.2.2. Any ideas?

(I would have put this as a comment, but I need reputation, you know the chicken and the egg thing)

- Session Info

R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.5.0 reshape2_1.4.1  dplyr_0.4.3     ggplot2_2.0.0   extrafontdb_1.0 extrafont_0.17  Rttf2pt1_1.3.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3      digest_0.6.9     assertthat_0.1   grid_3.2.2       plyr_1.8.3       R6_2.1.2         gtable_0.1.2
 [8] DBI_0.3.1        magrittr_1.5     scales_0.3.0     stringi_1.0-1    lazyeval_0.1.10  labeling_0.3     tools_3.2.2
[15] stringr_1.0.0    munsell_0.4.2    parallel_3.2.2   colorspace_1.2-6

Comment: You should probably ask [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts).

Comment: Hi from RStudio. :-) As @alistaire mentioned our support forum is probably the place for this question. We'd also be interested to know: (a) what's your `sessionInfo()`?, (b) what version of Windows are you running?, (c) does RStudio use a lot of CPU when this is happening?, (d) does turning off autocomplete help?

Comment: I added the session info. the packages are pretty straight forward. I am working on graphing, but the problems started soon after I loaded the new rstudio version. I will turn off autocomplete to see if it helps. I will also submit the question over to the RStudio support. Thank you for your help and patience.